# Grails unable to download dependencies behind proxy and firewall

Tags: grails

Title says it, Grails is unable to download dependencies behind my organization's proxy and firewall.  Now that I know what the problem is I need to tell my IT department to allow requests to those URLs through the firewall.  Based on the error messages Grails gave me I can determine that variants of...

http://grails.org

http://repo1.maven.org

...need to be let through the firewall, but I'm not sure if those two will get Grails everything it needs now, or in the future as I install plugins.

**What are all the domains/URLs Grails requests dependencies from?**

**Update:**

I gave the list of the domains @dmahapatro provided to my IT department and it seems Grails is now able to resolve dependencies correctly.  Here is a consolidated list of those domains:

http://grails.org

http://repo1.maven.org

http://repo.grails.org

http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org

http://repository.codehaus.org

http://download.java.net

http://repository.jboss.com

Comment: Have you configured your proxy in Grails? http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/set-proxy.html

Comment: My proxy is set at the system level, but I still tried what you suggested before I posted... no luck.  I think the corporate firewall is just blocking those addresses for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally it depends on the requirement of the application for dependencies. Ideally below items should resolve most of the dependencies (except if you want to refer some custom repo).

`//With reference to BuildConfig`

`grailsCentral()` - http://repo.grails.org/grails/core
`grailsPugins()` - http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins
`mavenCentral()` - http://repo1.maven.org
`artifactory` - http://repo.grails.org/grails

Additional repos are are also mentioned in `BuildConfig.groovy` as commented in newly created projects. (check their validity)

```
    // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable 
    //remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
    //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
```

Also, make sure if you have `inherits true` mentioned in the `repositories{..}` inside `BuildConfig`, the application inherits the repository definition from plugin. You need to make sure that is not blocked.

**Inference**
It totally depends on the nature of the application and the type of dependencies it needs to work as expected. Being said that, for a basic web application I think the above mentioned repository locations should suffice the purpose at enterprise level taking into consideration that company wide repositories like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) are is use as well.